# How do I make \widefbox bigger in the vertical direction?

Tags: amsmath, empheq

I want to enclose some equations in a widebox, but I need to make the box bigger the the y-direction/vertical direction. How is this done?

A sample code is given below (taken from the empheq manual).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{empheq}[box=widefbox]{align*}
a&=b \tag{*}\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please check your MWE produces the example that you expect. As posted that typesets `widefbox` before the equation.

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class, even for short examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\rule[-1.8cm]{0pt}{4cm}\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align*}
a&=b \tag{*}\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `\addstackgap` in the definition.  The optional argument (here 20pt) can be changed to suit.  This gap is an addition to the existing equation height/depth (rather than a replacement to it, which a `\rule` would be).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}\addstackgap[20pt]{#1}\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{align*}
a&=b \tag{*}\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1+ This is a more versatile solution!

Answer (score 2):

An indirect solution. Offsets definition provided by [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) allows more flexibility in customizing the frame size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\tikzset{offset definition 1/.style={
    above left offset={-0.4,0.6},
    below right offset={0.4,-0.5},
  },
  offset definition 2/.style={
    above left offset={-0.4,1.5},
    below right offset={0.4,-1.3},
  },
  filling/.style={
    disable rounded corners=true,
    set fill color=white,
    set border color=black,
  },
  box it 1/.style={
    offset definition 1,
    filling
  },
  box it 2/.style={
    offset definition 2,
    filling
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\tikzmarkin[box it 1]{a}a&=b \tag{*}\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx \tikzmarkend{a}
\end{align*}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{align*}
\tikzmarkin[box it 2]{b}a&=b \tag{*}\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx \tikzmarkend{b}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Remember to compile at least twice.